# Why do I get a FormatException when folding a List?

Tags: dart

I am trying to find the largest 5 digit number in a series, made up of consecutive digits.

**Code:**

```
import 'dart:math';

int solution(String digits) {
  List<int> sequence = digits.split('').map((digit) => int.parse(digit)).toList();
  List<int> fiveDigitNumbers = List<int>();

 sequence.fold(sequence, (remainder, digit) {
   fiveDigitNumbers.add(int.parse(remainder.take(5).join()));
   remainder = remainder.skip(5).toList();
     
   return remainder;
 });

   return fiveDigitNumbers.isEmpty ? 0:  fiveDigitNumbers.reduce((largest, number) => max(largest, number));
}

void main() {
  print(solution('12345').toString());
}
```

**Error:**

> FormatException: Invalid number (at character 1)
>
> ^

**Stack Trace:**

> dart:core                            int.parse
>
> package:solution/solution.dart 8:30  solution.
>
> dart:collection                      _ListBase&Object&ListMixin.fold
>
> package:solution/solution.dart 7:12  solution
>
> test/solution_test.dart 6:12         main.

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: I got a stack trace which shows the exception is thrown at line 8. `int.parse` throws the exception for String created by `join`-ing an empty List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace shows the exception is thrown at line 8 and column 30, which is the `int.parse()` call. `int.parse()` will throw that exception for an empty string. Joining an empty List will produce an empty string. The `remainder` list will get empty before `fold` has iterated over every digit. Rather use another looping construct, e.g. `while`.

```
int solution(String digits) {
  List<int> sequence = digits.split('').map((digit) => int.parse(digit)).toList();
  var fiveDigitNumbers = List<int>();

  while (! sequence.isEmpty) {
    fiveDigitNumbers.add(int.parse(sequence.take(5).join()));
    sequence = sequence.skip(1).toList();
  }

  return fiveDigitNumbers.isEmpty 
    ? 0
    : fiveDigitNumbers.reduce((largest, number) => max(largest, number));
}
```